# Are there quiet reflective survival-style blankets?

Tags: sleeping

Mylar heat blankets are very effective, especially for their size and weight. But they crinkle loudly.

Does anyone have personal experience with a reflective blanket that is quiet?

(My searches online and on YouTube discovered some claims, but no confirmations)

I guess another way of asking is "Is there such a thing as great reflective fabric that isn't crinkly?" Thanks.

Comment: These heat blankets are intended for emergencies, not as replacement for a sleeping bag. If you just cheated death, the noise is the least of your problems.

Comment: Similar to @PMF's comment, why does the noise matter? What use case do you have in mind where the noise is an issue?

Comment: As someone who travels light when cycling through the night, but might want a nap, I can see the appeal of an extra layer of warmth and wind protection in case clothing isn't enough. I actually bought a mylar foil bivvy bag for one trip when I expected 2-4 hours rest waiting for an early ferry, with nowhere to camp and no hotels with check-in in the small hours. When wild camping isn't allowed, using "emergency" gear to keep warm while "happening to fall asleep" during a "rest" is very different from setting up camp

Comment: ... So to make the most of that limited sleep time, probably in not a very comfortable position, it might conceivably be nice to not rustle at the slightest breath of wind

Answer (score 5):

Silvered tarps are quieter, but still far from silent, as well as being heavier and bulkier. But they're also far more reusable than foil blankets. I have one of a similar size to mylar blankets that I use underneath me, and a larger one as my tent. They certainly reflect heat, though probably less than the foil blankets. On the other hand they would wrap round you better.